# Perl archname for CPAN modules

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2, cpan, libxslt

Consider this [CPAN Tester Matrix Report](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=XML-LibXSLT%201.94;os=darwin;perl=5.20.2;reports=1) for OSX.

Sometimes `archname` is `darwin-2level`,sometimes its `darwin-thread-multi-2level`. 
I understand that it refers to if you are using Perl compiled with `-Dusethreads` flag or not.

1) But does that also signify that given module such as `XML::LibXML` or `XML::LibXSLT` is also compiled using/not using thread flag ?

2) Are there any such settings by which we can compile `XML::LibXML` and `XML::LibXSLT` with thread flags ?

3) Does the `archname` in the above report mandate that it will only work with Perl that is compiled without `-Dusethreads` flag ?

Answer (score 1):

When you install a module the same compiler flags are used for compiling the module that the flags used for compiling perl. Unless the module author decided otherwise in the `Makefile.PL`/`Build.PL` of the distribution.

Using different `usethreads` for a module than from the perl in which it will run would be dangerous (if even possible).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on question 3) ?